# What to set useState to for a User type in React Hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I'm new to hooks.  Not sure what `useState` should be set to for the initial value.

Right now an empty object `const [user, setUser] = useState({});` is set as the default value for `useState` and is causing `${crafter.id}`
to complain about `id` because there is no property `id` as it's trying to I guess use the default state for user which is set to {}.

**UserProfile.tsx**

```
interface UserProfileProps {
  userId: number;
  findUser: (userId: number) => Promise<User>;
}

const UserProfile = (props: UserProfileProps) => {
  const { userId, findUser } = props;
  const [user, setUser] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchUser = async () => {
      const user: User = await findUser(userId);
      setUser(user);
    };

    fetchUser();
  }, []);

  return (<div>User Id: ${user.id}</div>);
};

export default UserProfile;
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You should pass a generic parameter to `useState` so that TypeScript knows what the type of the value can be.

Also make sure only to try to get to the `id` property once the user has been retrieved, which can be done with optional chaining, and note that you don't need to type `user` as `User`, since `findUser` is already known to return `Promise<user>`:

```
const UserProfile = (props: UserProfileProps) => {
  const { userId, findUser } = props;
  const [user, setUser] = useState<User>(); // <---------------

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchUser = async () => {
      const user = await findUser(userId);
      setUser(user);
    };

    fetchUser();
  }, []);

  return (<div>User Id: ${user?.id}</div>);
  // could also only return this div if the user has been retrieved,
  // and return an empty element instead, if you wanted
};
```